# Correct place to define options in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

I have a jQuery plugin that uses namespacing (methods) and also has options, with defaults, that can be overridden on initialization.

I'm wondering what the best way to define and use options is with this plugin in the namespaces.

I was originally using a `$.fn.dropIt.settings` within the wrapper function to define the settings, but then switched to defining them inside of the `init` method. This is very limiting in terms of scope however..

Here is the relevant code in my plugin

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){
  var methods = {
      init: function(options)
      {
        var settings = $.extend({
          trigger: "hover",
          animation: 'slide', /* none, slide, fade, grow */
          easing: 'swing', /* swing, linear, bounce */
          speedIn: 400,
          speedOut: 400,
          delayIn: 0,
          delayOut: 0,
          initCallback: function(){},
          showCallback: function(){},
          hideCallback: function(){}
        }, options);

        $(this).each(function(index, ele){
          $ele = $(ele);
          $ele.addClass('dropit');
          //Attach event handlers to each list-item
          $('li', $ele).dropIt('attach', settings);

          //If list is displayed veritcally, add extra left padding to all sub-menus
          if($(ele).hasClass('vertical'))
          {
            $('li', $ele).find('ul').addClass('nested sub-menu');
          } else {
            $('li ul', $ele).addClass('nested').find('ul').addClass('sub-menu');
          }
        });

        //Call custom callback
        settings.initCallback.call();

        //Return jQuery collection of lists
        return $(this);
      },

      attach: ...

      _trigger: ...

      _hide: ...

      }
    };

  $.fn.dropIt = function(method){
    //Variables and Options
    var $this = $(this);
    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.dropIt' );
    }
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [jQuery Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page, I structured by plugin basically like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        // set default options
    }
    // internal functions
    var methods = {
        // plugin methods
    }
    $.fn.pluginName = function (method) {
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And, like you have, `$.extend` the defaults within the init method, but I like to keep the defaults declared separately, personally, for clarity.  It's been working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I always set the settings object as a global var to the plugin scope, like this:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){
  var settings; //NOTE THIS LINE

  var methods = {
      init: function(options)
      {
        settings = $.extend({ //AND THIS LINE
          trigger: "hover",
          animation: 'slide', /* none, slide, fade, grow */
          easing: 'swing', /* swing, linear, bounce */
          speedIn: 400,
          speedOut: 400,
          delayIn: 0,
          delayOut: 0,
          initCallback: function(){},
          showCallback: function(){},
          hideCallback: function(){}
        }, options);

        $(this).each(function(index, ele){
          $ele = $(ele);
          $ele.addClass('dropit');
          //Attach event handlers to each list-item
          $('li', $ele).dropIt('attach', settings);

          //If list is displayed veritcally, add extra left padding to all sub-menus
          if($(ele).hasClass('vertical'))
          {
            $('li', $ele).find('ul').addClass('nested sub-menu');
          } else {
            $('li ul', $ele).addClass('nested').find('ul').addClass('sub-menu');
          }
        });

        //Call custom callback
        settings.initCallback.call();

        //Return jQuery collection of lists
        return $(this);
      },

      attach: ...

      _trigger: ...

      _hide: ...

      }
    };

  $.fn.dropIt = function(method){
    //Variables and Options
    var $this = $(this);
    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.dropIt' );
    }
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**EDIT:**
You can also do `$(this).data('youPlugInName', settings)`, then if you want to change it latter you can retrieve this from `data('yourPlugInName')`, and update whatever property you  want.

Comment: If these are defined globally though, calling the plugin multiple times keeps any options set the first time it was called.  
  
If I set animation to 'fade' with one call to the plugin, and then initialize again on other elements, animation is still set to 'fade'.

Comment: Please, note my edit @ChristianBenincasa - have you tried that approach? What do you think?